# trying SSR but got "ServerStyleSheets is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I followed the Material-UI guide on the website to configure SSR, here's my server side code:

```
//server.js
...
...
...
const app = express();

app.use('/dist', express.static('dist'));

app.use((req, res) => {

  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();

  const html = renderToString(
    sheets.collect(
      <DataProvider>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <App />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </StaticRouter>
      </DataProvider>
    )
  );

  const css = sheets.toString();

  res.send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
        <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

        <title>My React App</title>
        <style id="jss-server-side">${css}</style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script src='main.js' async></script>
      </body>
    </html>
  `);
});
```

and here's my client side script:

```
//client.js
...
...
...
function Main() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const jssStyles = document.getElementById('jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <DataProvider>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <App />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </DataProvider>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}

hydrate(<Main />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It can build, but when visiting localhost, got this error:

```
TypeError: l.ServerStyleSheets is not a constructor
    at project-path/dist/main.js:1:301839
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (project-path/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at project-path/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

I'm using

"@material-ui/core": "^4.1.2", 
"express": "^4.17.1",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"webpack": "^4.41.2",

Please help me resolve this issue, I'm trying to add SSR to a already finished SPA...

Comment: source maps can help us

Comment: I realized in my @material-ui/core it doens't install ThemeProvider & ServerStyleSheets. I installed @material-ui/styles then it worked.